# React Admin: ReferenceArrayField is not passing data to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-admin

I am trying to display a datagrid of media of a product from a list of media ids. Using ReferenceArrayField component, the getMany() function of the media data provider is called. The fetching is working fine.

However, the data fetched is not passed by the ReferenceArrayField component to its child DataGrid.

I really don't get what is happening here, might be a bug.

```
<ReferenceArrayField label="Médias" reference="mediaResource" source="mediasIds">
            <DataGrid>
                <UrlField source="finalUrl" label="Miniature" target="_blank" />
                <TextField source="type" />
            </DataGrid>
</ReferenceArrayField>
```